# Immutable.js - toJS Is Not A Function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, immutability, immutable.js

I am getting the typeError when I try using this function.

As per the [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/toJS) docs, I want to convert an obj into normal JS obj.

Here is the example:

```
import { Map as iMap,
         toJS } from "immutable";

    let anExample = iMap({
        a : "a",
        b : "b"
    });
    console.log( "anExample is...", toJS( anExample ) );
```

I do not get an error on `Map`, but I do on `toJS`. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like it is defaulting to the [`native Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) rather than immutable's Map. Is immutable installed? This would also explain why `toJS` isn't defined...

Comment: yes it is. And I do not think its defaulting to native as I'm referencing the 'immutable' 'Map' function to 'iMap' (Line1) & I get the correct `console.log` when I log 'anExample'

Comment: Oh wait! I see the issue. one min, I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not need to import `toJS`, since it's found on the immutable object itself. Based on your example, you would go about it like so:

```
import { Map as iMap } from "immutable";

let anExample = iMap({
    a : "a",
    b : "b"
});
console.log( "anExample is...", anExample.toJS() );
```

---

Another way you could go about this is to import [`fromJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS). `fromJS` is a "lazy" way of converting JS to immutable; however, it is not ideal if you need particular Immutable structures (like an `OrderedSet` rather than a `List`).

You would handle that like this:

```
import { fromJS } from "immutable";

let anExample = fromJS({
    a : "a",
    b : "b"
});
console.log( "anExample is...", anExample.toJS() );
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you.